# OpenCv convexityDefects returning more defects

Tags: java, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to count the "defects" of this image using Opencv for Java.
[image]

As you can see this is a 21 points-star, which means there should be 21 connectivity defects after applying the convex-hull method.
However, `convexityDefects()` is returning a total of 23 defects.
**Why there are 2 more defects?**

[image]

Comment: there is an [issue](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/5908) about that problem

Comment: @sturkmen you can post this as an answer, detailing which version is affected by the bug, and eventually updating the answer when the bug is solved.

Comment: i have no wider knowledge about the problem. maybe [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/81942) will help a bit more.